# Firebase Snapshot iteration order

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I iterate through a firebase snapshot with a sample code like this:

```
var ref = Firebase(url:MY_FIREBASE_URL)
ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as [FDataSnapshot] {
       println(rest.value)     
    }
})
```

Is there a way to guarantee that the iteration will be in order of creation of children in the node?

Comment: `snapshot.children` is in the order you requested the children from the database. To specify a specific order, use `queryOrderedByKey`, `queryOrderedByValue` or `queryOrderedByChild`. See the Firebase documentation on ordering: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sort_data

Comment: Do you think the uid are created in alphabetic order? If so, I can just order on UID ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with UID here. The database results can be order by their key, their value or the value of a child.

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee the order of the children, use [.childByAutoId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)childByAutoId) when generating a new child of a Firebase Database location. As the reference states, this key is prefixed with a timestamp. Then as Frank says, you can use queryOrderedByKey to specify a specific order. Since the children are timestamped, this order would be the order of creation.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not how this firebase database was designed. It adds a new user_id as a child node everytime a new anonymous user logs in. My question is if I can go through these child user_id nodes in the order they were created. I do not have a timestamp in the data, neither have I created data through .childByAutoId